# Visual Studio 2015: Visualization of std::vector doesn't show information in debug

Tags: c++, debugging, vector, visual-studio-2015

I installed a new update of visual studio 2015 and have now the version 14.0.25424.00 with update 3.
After installing the update the visualization of std::vectors while debugging changed. Usually when I debugged a program I could see the size and the items of a std::vector.

After the update I only can see the raw view of the std::vector.

[image: Visualization of a vector in the 'Locals' window]

Here is the code which I used to for this example:

```
int main()
{
   int a = 1;
   std::vector<int> vecOfInt;
   vecOfInt.push_back(1);
   vecOfInt.push_back(2);
   vecOfInt.push_back(3);

   return 0;
}
```

I think that maybe during the update some settings in visual studio changed but I can't find out what is different... 
Does anyone has an idea what I could try to fix this besides reinstalling visual studio?

EDIT:
Here the requested debug settings:
[image]

Comment: Please show your project settings. Also, ensure you are compiling under "debug" configuration

Comment: Did you check debug symbols are loaded in modules window ?

Comment: I could not reproduce this with update2. Now Installing update3 to test.

Comment: I could not get update3 to install. After downloading update3 it gives me an option to upgrade to upgrade2 and reports I already have that. I see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/vs-knownissues/vs2015-update3

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem. Repairing the update fixed it.

Go to Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Programs and Features -> View Installed Updates -> Right click on Visual Studio Update 3 -> Change -> Repair

Answer (score 1):

I debug it in my two VS2015 machines Enterprise and community 14.0.25424.00 version.

I found that the option "Use Native Compatibility Mode" will impact the std::vector size in the local or Watch window. If I disable it, it works well in my side.

Maybe you could reset your VS settings and debug it again.

TOOLS->Import and Export Settings Wizard->Reset all settings->select “No, just reset settings, overwriting my current settings”->Choose a Default Collection of settings.

[image]

Comment: What is your VS2015 version, English community version or others? Do you use the Windows 10 or others? Do you reset your VS settings? I often select the C# settings, and then disable  "Use Native Compatibility Mode", it really works well in my side. If it doesn't work, it would be related to the VS IDE. Do you test it in other VS2015 Environment?

Comment: Resetting finally put my vs 2013 (w/ update 5) into a great state!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Win7 x64, VS2015 Update3 (ver 14.0.25431.01).

I tried repair Update 3 as described in WinterMute's answer (incl. reboot) - it didn't help.

I tried reset my setting in VS as described in Jack's answer:
TOOLS->Import and Export Settings Wizard->Reset all settings->select “No, just reset settings, overwriting my current settings”-> I chose a "General" collection. (+ restart VS)
It helped. And I noticed 1 change in `Options > Debugging > General`: `Use Managed Compatibility Mode` is **unchecked** now. (I have also `Use Native Compatibility Mode` unchecked but it was before too).
Both `std::vector` and `std::stack` are shown nice in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

I have to disable "Show raw structure of objects in variables Window" in Visual Studio, under
Debug > Options > Debugging > General

[image]